# Large text not displaying as multiple lines for UILabel in a custom tableview cell

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard, tableview, uilabel

Setting up the UILabel on the attributes inspector as follow expands the cell and display the large text as multiple lines correctly for a Subtitle tableview cell:

Lines = 0

Line Break = Word wrap

But this doesn't work in a custom tableview cell for some reasons.  In the custom cell, I added new labels and setup the attributes the same way but the cell doesn't expand.

Comment: What's the height of the label guy?

Comment: @ElTomato it's 21

Comment: How do you show two lines of text or more with it?  Is the font size 10.0?

Comment: @ElTomato they're both size 17.0

Comment: You should check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights

Comment: Can you show some code?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a matter of constraint.
Check to see if there are any conflicting constraints or fixed settings.

[image]

In order for elements of a cell to be set flexibly, the height of the cell must be set to the `automatic` value.

[image]

When I set it up like this, I was able to get the results I wanted.

[image]